# Access statics from this?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have the following class in ExtJS 5.1:

```
Ext.define('Web.view.guard.apps.conexao.Conexao', {
    extend: 'Web.view.guard.apps.App',

    width: 400,
    height: 600,

    statics: {
        title: 'Conexão',
        icon: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg'
    },
});
```

I want to access the static attributes from the instance context, like `title = this.statics.title` or something like this, from the controller or the view itself, but I can't find a way in the documentation.

I found through Google a reference to a method `statics()`, but it doesn't work, `this.statics().title` returns `null`, although the `statics()` method do exists.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way is

```
Web.view.guard.apps.conexao.Conexao.title
```

But `this.self` is a reference to `Web.view.guard.apps.conexao.Conexao`, so you can use `this.self.title`. See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Base-property-self and https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/na0

```
Ext.define('Web.view.guard.apps.conexao.Conexao', {
    extend: 'Web.view.guard.apps.App',

    width: 400,
    height: 600,

    statics: {
        title: 'Conexão',
        icon: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg'
    },

    myInstanceMethod: function() {
        console.log(this.self.title); 
    }
});
var conn = new Web.view.guard.apps.conexao.Conexao();
conn.myInstanceMethod();  
// 'Conexão' 
// 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg'
```

If you want it to be accessible to subclasses, be sure to use `inheritableStatics: {}` instead.

Comment: or `this.self.title`.

Comment: @CD.. My initial response was incorrect because Ext actually overrides the `constructor` property of objects (breaking a JavaScript convention that instances have a property called constructor that points back the to "class" itself). `constructor` points to the function that Ext ends up calling from the real constructor (which you can pass in the object that is the argument to `Ext.define`, or a default one is created for you). Thanks for keeping my honest. See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/na0

Comment: Your fiddle test is amazing! Thanks for that! Great answer.